# Apache Spark: Why are many small dataframes so much slower than few big ones?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

So I am having the following scenario:

I have a service where I do some calculation on parameters in a dataframe. For example I am doing the describe() operation. I got the parameters via and http-post (Array[String]+schema) and read them in via read.json function on the sql context.

I can either get it in one one big dataframe with 10.000 parameters or in 10.000 small dataframes with just one parameter. Each having around 12.000 rows with timestamps.
In the end I need to collect the dataframe(s) to send it to a different service for further calculations. It would be easier to to it parameter wise, because of the way the input is created.

But I figured out, that doing the collecting/converting to json on the many small dataframes is way more expensive than on the one huge dataframe.
For the big dataframe taking about 6 seconds and all small ones at least 20 seconds. For one this does not seem to be so important but I want to do it on at least 3000 of these 10.000 parameter inputs.

Why is that so? It does not seem to be the difference in calculation, but the difference in collecting it once vs many times.

Comment: "It does not seem to be the difference in calculation, but the difference in collecting it once vs many times.". Yep.

Answer (score 0):

When you call collect(), Spark must submit job and send data to one node.

Let's consider 10 DataFrames of n elements and one with 10n elements.

One big collect() -> 10n data is sent, one execution plan and one job created
10 DataFrames -> 10*collect() -> 10*n data is sent, 10 execution plans needs to be generated and 10 jobs submited.

Of course it depends also on hardware and network, i.e. if you can have small DataFrame on one node then it *may* be faster than sending over network.